# dplyr medians of rows based on grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Let say this is my example data:

```
gene_data=data.frame(gene=c("g1","g2","g3","g4"),
sample1=c(12,25,73,84),
sample2=c(54,65,89,97),
sample3=c(45,25,6,8),
sample4=c(23,23,45,6))
```

I want to get median expression of each gene, when I try this it does not work.

```
gene_data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(medians=median(.))
```

Since it warns me about non-numeric column which is the first "gene" column...

However, this one works quite well:

```
gene_data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(medians=median(sample1:sample4))
```

This one creates an output like this, which is I want: (THIS TABLE IS WRONG, be careful, so this is not I want)

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
gene medians
<fctr>   <dbl>
1     g1    17.5
2     g2    24.0
3     g3    59.0
4     g4    45.0
```

But I need a general solution, and I do now want summarise_each, which apply median to all genes and that is wrong.

Not necessarily I know the name of the samples, so I want to get median expressions without knowing the sample names at the beginning and at the end.

For example,

```
gene_data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(medians=median([the numeric columns, or column that contain something]))
```

Perhaps it is too easy, but I could not find for Dplyr. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need `summarise_each` i.e. `gene_data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise_each(funs(medians=median(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: Look at `?summarise_if` and `?summarise_at`

Comment: Nope I need an output like this # A tibble: 4 × 2
    gene medians
  <fctr>   <dbl>
1     g1    17.5
2     g2    24.0
3     g3    59.0
4     g4    45.0

Comment: If you are looking for median per row , `library(matrixStats);rowMedians(as.matrix(gene_data[-1]))`

Comment: BTW, the output I am getting with your code is not correct `median`

Comment: Yes I want it per row, is there solution in dplyr ??

Comment: `gather(gene_data, sample, value, starts_with("sample")) %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(median = median(value))`

Comment: Yes you are right, gene_data %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(medians=median(sample1:sample4)) this does not create the correct solution as well.

Comment: Here is one `gene_data %>% group_by(gene) %>% do(data.frame(medians = median(unlist(.[-1]))))`

Comment: Thanks gather works like a charm !!!!

Comment: Thanks akrun , that also works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `do`

```
library(dplyr)
gene_data %>%
   group_by(gene) %>% 
   do(data.frame(medians = median(unlist(.[-1]))))
```